# How can I format the current date and time and then use them in a variable with GoTest?

Tags: datetime, variables, timestamp, automated-tests, format

I use the keyword...

> get date

But I have a date with the format like this

> Sun May 11,2014 9:60 p.m.

I need to convert it in to this format 2014.05.11.09.60.60.321
I tried to put this **yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss.ff** in the format arg field... I tried to put the format in the variable to, but its not working ether :(
I dont know what to do to use the current datetime (stamp) as a variable!
[image result exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqm7F.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution...

1. use the keyword : get current date
2. set return variable ${stamp}
3. in the format arg, use "%" like this %Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S.%f
4. now you can use the variable
   [image result exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkEqa.png)